# R: How to fill area between these two dashed lines

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, forecasting, confidence-interval

my name is Ihsan, sorry for my English if it's not understandable,

I need help to create a shade or to fill the area between these two dashed lines as my forecast "interval"

[image: Figure]

My data is (as ts object):

```
ts
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
2018   0 208 112  39  65  38  17  54 105   0  66  24
2019   0   0  69 421   0   0   0   0   0   0   0  10
```

My code is:

```
library('tsintermittent')

ts <- structure(
  c(0L, 208L, 112L, 39L, 65L, 38L, 17L, 54L, 105L, 0L, 66L, 24L,
    0L, 0L, 69L, 421L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 10L),
  .Tsp = c(2018, 2019 + 11/12, 12), class = 'ts'
)

crost.frc <- crost(ts,h=3,w=NULL,init="mean",nop=1,type="croston",
                   cost=c("mae","mse"),init.opt = F,
                   outplot = F,opt.on = F,na.rm = F)

tsobj <- ts(c(ts,rep(NA,3)),frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))

fit <- ts(crost.frc$frc.in,frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))

y <- ts(c(fit,crost.frc$frc.out),frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))

upconfint <- ts(c(rep(NA,23),fit[24],y[25:27]+1.96*sd(ts-na.omit(fit))),
                frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))
lowconfint <- ts(c(rep(NA,23),fit[24],y[25:27]-1.96*sd(ts-na.omit(fit))),
                frequency=12,start=c(2018,1))

#Plot Forecast - Croston
plot(tsobj,pch=16,type="o",main="Metode Croston",xlab="Periode",ylab="Demand")

points(y,pch=1,type="o",col="purple")

points(upconfint,type="l",lty=3,col="grey",lwd=2)
points(lowconfint,type="l",lty=3,col="grey",lwd=2)

points(fit,pch=1,type="o",col="red")

legend("topleft", legend=c("Aktual","Fit","Forecast","Interval"),
       col=c("black","red","purple","grey"), lty=c(1,1,1,2), cex=0.8)
```

I'm really looking forward to your suggestion, thank you!

Comment: be sure to add the output of `dput(object)` and any libraries you are using to your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never work with time series so this could be the hard way.

If you have data like this

```
x <- 1:5
y <- 1:5
```

Then your call to `polygon` should look like this

```
polygon(c(x, rev(x)), c(y, rev(y)))
```

To get the x-values, what is used in `stats:::lines.ts` is `time(ts)` where `ts` is each of your `upconfint` and `lowconfint`.

But you're going to have to re-order your plotting if you want the confidence interval drawn under the other parts:

```
plot(tsobj,pch=16,type="o",main="Metode Croston",xlab="Periode",ylab="Demand")

xx <- c(time(upconfint), rev(time(lowconfint)))
yy <- c(upconfint, rev(lowconfint))
polygon(xx, yy, col = 'grey95', border = NA)

points(upconfint,type="l",lty=3,col="grey",lwd=2)
points(lowconfint,type="l",lty=3,col="grey",lwd=2)

points(y,pch=1,type="o",col="purple")
points(fit,pch=1,type="o",col="red")

legend("topleft", legend=c("Aktual","Fit","Forecast","Interval"),
       col=c("black","red","purple","grey"), lty=c(1,1,1,2), cex=0.8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! that actually answers my confusion, because the x-axis are time points, and I don't know how to return that as an input in polygon function